# Blazor Webassembly - Putting/Posting to API Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, post, blazor-webassembly, put

I have a controller - roughed out below.  And then you see the call I make from the client.
When I make the client call to post, it gives me a Bad Request error.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MainController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(Policies policy)
    {
    myModelContext.Policies.Update(policy);
    myModelContext.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
    }
}

//client code
protected async void OnUpdating(GridCommandEventArgs editRow)
{
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"Main", (Policies)editRow.Item);

    if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        
toastService.ShowError(httpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

I've tried everything

Comment: Is the server method called? Did you try to add [FromBody] attribute?  "Post([FromBody] Policies policy)"

Comment: Are the models you are passing consistent? Is it possible to see the passed parameter value in the browser's developer tools? Can you provide a reproducible minimal example in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: This link may help you: [Call a web API from ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly).

Comment: The link Chen gave is great for the client side code.  But I also need to see what the Controller should look like.  My controller method never gets called.  It's not making it to the Controller.